# Connection Reset for Vert.x mailsender on keep alive timeout

Tags: java, smtp, vert.x, quarkus

We have an application based on Quarkus (2.4.2), and its mailsender is Vert.x Mailer.
Config used:

```
quarkus.mailer.host=smtp.office365.com
quarkus.mailer.keep-alive-timeout=PT60S
quarkus.mailer.keep-alive=true
```

The issue we are having is that 60 seconds after a mail is sent the following is logged:

```
2021-11-25T09:48:58.477+0100 ERROR [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] io.vertx.ext.mail.impl.SMTPConnection Connection reset: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:367)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:398)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:367)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:398)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Based on this stacktrace it looks like it is smtp.office365.com that do `Connection reset`, timeout handling in Vert.x' SMTPConnection [should close gracefully](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mail-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/mail/impl/SMTPConnection.java#L330).

Does anyone have any experiences like this?

Silencing logging for SMTPConnection is an option, but that does not seem right.

Comment: This is the regular exception when this happens. Any reason to use a long-running connection? If you open an issue with a reproducer I can have a look to see if we can catch the exception in a more graceful manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation after stepping through the code is that [SMTPConnection.quitCloseConnection](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mail-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/mail/impl/SMTPConnection.java#L330) is missing a call for closing the actuall connection.

So `QUIT` is sent, then the smtp-server sends `connection reset` since the connection is not closed.

I created an issue in [vert.x mail client](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mail-client/issues/175).